# Add character to specific value in rows by condition

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement, lapply

lets say we have following data:

```
    df1 = data.frame(cm= c('10129', '21120', '123456','345239'), 
                     num=c(6,6,6,6))

 >  df1

cm      num
10129    6
21120    6
123456   6
345      4
```

as you see the length of some boxes in the `cm` column is 6 digits and some of 5 digits. I want to code the following: if the number of digits in the `cm` column is less than number in `num` column, add 0 value in the front to get the given output:

```
cm      num
010129    6
021120    6
123456    6
0345      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_pad`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% mutate(cm = str_pad(cm, num, "left", "0"))
#>       cm num
#> 1 010129   6
#> 2 021120   6
#> 3 123456   6
#> 4   0345   4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Input Data**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(cm  = c('10129', '21120', '123456','345'), num = c(6,6,6,4))

df1
#>       cm num
#> 1  10129   6
#> 2  21120   6
#> 3 123456   6
#> 4    345   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simplest using `dplyr` and `nchar`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(cm = if_else(nchar(cm) < num, paste0(0, cm), cm))
```

```
      cm num
1  10129   6
2  21120   6
3 123456   6
4 345239   6
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941494/how-to-increase-speed-efficiency-of-code

Answer (score 1):

The other `tidyverse`/`dplyr` answers are nicer, but if you want to stick to base R for some reason:

```
df1$cm <- ifelse(nchar(df1$cm) < df1$num, paste0('0', df1$cm), df1$cm)

df1
#>       cm num
#> 1 010129   6
#> 2 021120   6
#> 3 123456   6
#> 4 345239   6
```